# Cancel a timer in an ngrx effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

I have a spinner I want the spinner to wait for x number of seconds before it is shown. However if REQUEST_DEACTIVATE_SPINNER is called during the time the spinner is waiting for the timeout to complete, it should stop the ACTIVATE_SPINNER action from being fired. Aka I would like to cancel the active timer. This is what I have so far.

```
  @Effect() spinnerActive$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(REQUEST_ACTIVATE_SPINNER, REQUEST_DEACTIVATE_SPINNER)
    .switchMap(action => {
      // create a timer and return it active event sent when timer completes
      if (action.type === REQUEST_ACTIVATE_SPINNER) {
        timer$ = Observable.timer(action.payload.delay || 0)
        .switchMap(() =>
          Observable.of({type: ACTIVATE_SPINNER})
        );
      }

      if (action.type === REQUEST_DEACTIVATE_SPINNER) {
        // check to see if a timer is running if it is cancel it
        if (timer$) {
          // cancel the timer
        }
        return Observable.of({type: DEACTIVATE_SPINNER});
      }
    });
```

Could some body possibly show we how to cancel a timer that is being returned to an Effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to solve your problem using the [`takeUntil` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil).

You could use it to complete the observable in the `switchMap` for the `REQUEST_ACTIVATE_SPINNER` effect when a `REQUEST_DEACTIVATE_SPINNER` action is received.

Note that there are now two effects, as the `REQUEST_DEACTIVATE_SPINNER` effect is now independent of the `REQUEST_ACTIVATE_SPINNER` effect:

```ts
@Effect() spinnerActive$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(REQUEST_ACTIVATE_SPINNER)
  .switchMap(action => Observable
    .timer(action.payload.delay || 0)
    .takeUntil(this.actions$.ofType(REQUEST_DEACTIVATE_SPINNER))
    .switchMap(() => Observable.of({ type: ACTIVATE_SPINNER })
  );

@Effect() spinnerDeactive$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(REQUEST_DEACTIVATE_SPINNER)
  .switchMap(action => Observable.of({ type: DEACTIVATE_SPINNER }));
```

Also, the some of the `switchMap` operators are unnecessary and could be replaced with `mapTo`:

```ts
@Effect() spinnerActive$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(REQUEST_ACTIVATE_SPINNER)
  .switchMap(action => Observable
    .timer(action.payload.delay || 0)
    .takeUntil(this.actions$.ofType(REQUEST_DEACTIVATE_SPINNER))
    .mapTo({ type: ACTIVATE_SPINNER })
  );

@Effect() spinnerDeactive$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(REQUEST_DEACTIVATE_SPINNER)
  .mapTo({ type: DEACTIVATE_SPINNER });
```

Comment: Great answer and pattern.

Answer (score -3):

Call `unsubscribe()` on your subscription (sorry, `$timer` is `Observable` itself) when you need to kill timer manually. It is disposed when there is no more subscriptions applied to it.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue I'm having is doing exactly that (calling unsubscribe) with ngrx effects. In effects you return the observable to the store so the store is then subscribed to it. I have no idea how to get it to unsubscribe.

Comment: This answer does not work with ngrx Effect. You should not subscribe to a effect, NgRx does it behind the scenes.